# Composing Iterators

Tags: scala

Say I have the following function definition:

```
def print(input:Iterator[String]) : Iterator[String] = {
  Iterator.continually {
     val item = input.next
     item + item
  }
}
```

given the input

```
List("1", "2", "3").iterator
```

I want the output to be equal to

```
List("11", "22", "33").iterator
```

The problem is that when I use `Iterator.continually`, I am forced to iterate through the list using a `takeWhile`. I would like to be able to use any Iterator function that exists (fold, filter, etc...) without getting a "next on empty iterator" exception.

You can do this in F# using seq and yield. I was hoping that `Iterator.continually` would be just as robust.

F# example:

```
seq {
   for i in input |> yield i + i
}
```

P.S. I realize I could just compose a bunch of functions and then pass them to an Iterator function but I'm trying to compose Iterators in a way that I could in F#.

Comment: Do you already know about [Streams](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream)?

Comment: The question is not clear at all to me. You could have just called `map` on `input` to accomplish that (`input.map(x => x + x)`), but it seems that this wouldn't solve your use case, just your example. However, I have no idea what your use case is.

Comment: I don't know about streams, are they better for this kind of problem?

Comment: I think maybe you're looking for `Iterator.map`? `List("1", "2", "3").iterator.map(x => x+x)`

Comment: Iterator.map does not return an iterator

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz - Streams are for infinite lazy data, which I thought might be what you were looking for since you're trying to use `continually`. However, I think Christopher Martin's suggestion to just use `map` is what you want. And it _does_ return an iterator.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz, can you include an example of the F# seq and yield, and expected results? I'm sure we can then translate it in multiple ways and let you know the pros and cons and limitations.

Comment: oh, well if map returns an iterator then my problem seems even more ambiguous. I will write the F# example.

Comment: I hope my F# example is clear.

Comment: I thought that map in scala returns a List?

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz - Usually `map` returns the same type as the input collection (although the type parameters can change) if at all possible. There are some weird cases when it doesn't quite work (although I can't remember any at the moment), but for the most part it will do the right thing. For example, `for ( (a,b) <- Map(1->2, 3->4) ) yield (b,a)` results in `Map(2 -> 1, 4 -> 3)`.

Comment: Map on List returns List. Map on Iterable returns Iterable. Map on Iterator returns Iterator. Et cetera...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `List.map` will do what you want. However, you might want to use Scala's for comprehension syntax, which the compiler just translates into a `map` call. Here's a snippet from a test in my REPL. Seems to work.

```
scala> def print(input:Iterator[String]) : Iterator[String] =
     |   for (i <- input) yield i + i
print: (input: Iterator[String])Iterator[String]

scala> print( List("a", "b", "c").iterator )
res0: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> res0.toList
res1: List[String] = List(aa, bb, cc)
```

Comment: The `for`-`yield` syntax is sugar for `map` and `flatMap`. `for (i <- input) yield i + i` is equivalent to `input.map(i => i + i)`.